# Change form selection based on referrer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form in which a user is asked to select one of two items. I want to make it so that if they come from a specific page on my site one of the options is already selected for them. I can't seem to do this without breaking my form.

Here's what the form element looks like:

```
<div class="container-fluid selectLoanPurpose">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason1" value="one" required><span>reason1</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason2" value="two" required><span>reason2</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
<div class="container-fluid selectLoanPurpose">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <?php if ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == '/reasons') { ?>
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason1" value="one" required checked><span>reason1</span></label>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason1" value="one" required><span>reason1</span></label>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason2" value="two" required><span>reason2</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. None of them have worked and my form no longer loads, I just get a white screen.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "breaks". What happens? Also, I don't know if you tried that exact code, but you're missing a { on `<?php } else ?>` this line

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have edited my question to add the bracket and explain that the form just doesn't load when I run that code. Yes, I've tried the code. I'll try it again to make sure the missing bracket wasn't the issue.

Comment: if user want check one of them means you need to keep both radio name attribute to same name . and differentiate by the value

Comment: The missing curly brace was the issue as far as the form breaking, but it still doesn't select the option I want it to select.

Comment: If the page doesn't load at all its likely you have PHP errors turned off in your development environment, firstly view source and see if anything is coming through at all - then turn errors on to see what's going wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Blank page probably means PHP error with display_errors set to Off. Add this to the top of the page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and you'll get more information

Comment: Can you see exactly what $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is outputting, put <?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']; die(); ?> at the top of your script

Comment: When I place <?php echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']; die(); ?> at the top of my script I get nothing coming back.

Comment: Use $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

Comment: Ok, that time I got the /page that my form lives at. I need to get the page that the user was one before they came to my form.

Comment: Use $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] then.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>
<div class="container-fluid selectLoanPurpose">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        <?php if (strpos($referrer, '/reasons') > -1) { // here we am checking that what ever the URL is but should contain /reason ?>
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason1" value="one" required checked><span>reason1</span></label>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason1" value="one" required><span>reason1</span></label>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="choose"><input type="radio" name="reason2" value="two" required><span>reason2</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this one.